# Autocomplete does not Highlights default Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, material-ui

Somehow my default Value of my Autocomplete does not get selected.
It only gets selected after you click it from the menu yourself.

**Assumption**
Could this maybe come from the filter method because this return a new Object reference and therefore its not possible to preselect inside the Menu ?

**Data-Set Sample**

```
...
    { icon: '', name: 'French Polynesia', abbr: 'PF', code: '689' },
    { icon: '', name: 'French Southern Territories', abbr: 'TF', code: '262' },
    { icon: '', name: 'Gabon', abbr: 'GA', code: '241' },
    { icon: '', name: 'Gambia', abbr: 'GM', code: '220' },
    { icon: '', name: 'Georgia', abbr: 'GE', code: '995' },
    { icon: '', name: 'Germany', abbr: 'DE', code: '49', suggested: true },
...
```

**Autocomplete Component**

```
<Autocomplete
    fullWidth
    id="grouped-countries"
    options={options.sort(
        (a, b) => -b.groupLabel.localeCompare(a.groupLabel),
    )}
    defaultValue={
        //Pass Object with name Germany as Default!
        options.filter((obj) => obj.name === 'Germany')[0]
    }
    groupBy={(option) => option.groupLabel}
    noOptionsText="keine passendes Land"
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
    renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            {...params}
            fullWidth
            label="Land"
            defaultValue={
                //Set Default Input Value to Germany!
                options.filter((obj) => obj.name === 'Germany')[0].name
            }
            className={classes.input}
        />
    )}
    Menu
/>
```

**Output // Example**

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-autocomplete-fail-7uh04

Comment: It is being selected as expected!

Comment: This behaviour  is not consistent. Sometimes it get selected inside the Menu and sometimes it does not. It feels like arbitrary behaviour.

Comment: If you are doing it on `codesanbox`, then it could be the reason. Many times I face some weirdness coding on it.

Comment: This behavior originally occurred on my local machine. The Sandbox is just a reference / example.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on your codesandbox. `filter` only removes the objects from the array, it should not change the object references